# Clip set and clip release in Inkscape

Tags: vector, inkscape, path, clipping-mask, path-effects

Could someone, please, explain me dumb proof what is a clip set and what is a clip release?

I learned how to make an inner shadow in Inkscape using Clip->Set, but I am still confused what is happening when I apply it.

I read [the](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-what-are-clipping-and-masking-in-inkscape--vector-24947) article. And from it I started to think that Clip Set just an operation which finds the intersection of two provided objects and deletes the upper. And it is seems to be so, because it does not contradict to how I created the inner shadow. And article did not manage do explain me what the Clip Release is.

So, does Clip Set really just the intersection which deletes the upper object and what is Clip Release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clipping Paths explained for dummies? sure!

Cut a hole in a piece of paper with some scissors. Place the paper over another piece of paper with a drawing or picture on it.  That's what a clipping path does. You can see the drawing through the hole.

Release it, and you take away top piece of paper, and you can now see the entire drawing again.

Comment: The shape of the whole is determined by the object which is at the top at the time of clipping. Did I get it right?

Comment: @trafalgarLaww are you a troll?

Comment: No. I am not...

Comment: So, could you please answer my question - the topmost comment?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - No that isn't quite right. You could easily apply a clipping path to an entire document composed of many elements - just group them, and apply the clipping path to the group.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - I didn't say you said that! Your assertion that a clipping path "can be applied to only a single object, as opposed to the entire document" is not quite right. Although it's true it has to be a single object, a group can be clipped. In any case, I think your clarification is irrelevant to what the OP asked, which was for a "dumb proof" description of what a clipping path does, and what releasing a clipping path does.  The OP did not want this level of detail, and it's therefore irrelevant to the question asked, and therefore I think your clarification is unneccessary.

Comment: @BillyKerr We're talking past each other. I'll re-phrase my original comment.

Comment: @trafalgarLaww You got it right. Additionally, clipping can apply to a single object or a group of objects; not just the entire drawing.

Comment: @trafalgarLaww - Yes, I understand that totally, but on GDSE we are supposed to concentrate on the actual question, and when asked specifically by the OP to dumb it down, that is exactly what I tried by providing a very simple analogy. It didn't really work though (as you can see if you read the first comment). I seriously doubt that adding further info would have improved the situation. Sometimes answering even what to us may seem like a simple (or obvious) question, is often quite difficult in the face of such obtuseness. Although I suppose that's the challenge!